# What happened to Fairy Tail Monthly?

Tags: fairy-tail-zero

Since July 17th 2014, [Fairy Tail Monthly](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Fairy_Tail_Wiki:Sorcerer_Magazine/Monthly) has been released. Every month at the 17th it is supposed to come out with the aim to:

> - Entertain
> - Inform users of important series information, rumors, funfacts, trivia, etc.
> - Inform users of ongoing important votes, discussions, and articles needing improvement
> - Provide users with a quick summary of happenings in the past month, e.g. user rights changes, major community decisions, discussion results
> - Keep users updated with the latest contests, community activities, etc.

It should also contain a chapter of [Fairy Tail Zero](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Fairy_Tail_Zero), written by Hiro Mashima. Since the chapter is due 11 days now, it made me wonder whether something has happened to the magazine. Was it not yet released in Japan due to Golden Week? Or did the magazine just not contain a chapter this month? Is there anyone that might know more about the magazine and the chapter?

Comment: That seems to be a magazine by Fairy Tail Wiki, not by the author.

Comment: @nhahtdh I see, you are correct, he only writes the series, but that doesn't change the question though as to what has happened to the may-release?

Comment: I found chapter 11 spoilers here, so I guess it's delay on the scanlation's side, not the author http://tuttoanimemanga.forumcommunity.net/?t=56581337